# Why installing glfw through apt-get works but manually compiling failed

Tags: c, ubuntu, opengl, glfw

I tried to install glfw3 in ubuntu 16. I first followed the instruction in [glfw docs](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile_guide.html): downloaded the source of glfw, built it into shared library by setting

```
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
```

and installed it by typing:

```
sudo make install
```

But the installation failed. When I tried to compile the sample code found [there](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs487/glfw-howto/sample.cpp), some undefined reference errors appeared:

```
undefined reference to `glfwSetErrorCallback'
undefined reference to `glfwInit'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
undefined reference to `glfwSetKeyCallback'
undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
undefined reference to `glfwGetProcAddress'
undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
undefined reference to `glfwGetFramebufferSize'
undefined reference to `glfwGetTime'
undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
undefined reference to `glfwGetTime'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
undefined reference to `glfwTerminate
```

My compiling command was:

```
g++ glfwtest.c -lglfw -lGL
```

But when I changed my approach, and installed glfw3 directly using apt-get by typing:

```
sudo agt-get install libglwf3-dev
```

My test code was successfully compiled with the same compiling command.

It is wired, does anyone know why?

Comment: Did you run `make` before `sudo make install`?

Comment: Yes I did. The build was success, but somehow my test code could not link to the shared library.

Comment: That's actually `apt-get install libglfw3-dev`